# How can I check if all subscriptions are ready?

Tags: meteor

I know how to do that in Template level and even in route level. What I wanted was to get a reactive var to check for all subscribed vars ready-ness.

I can check with DDP._allSubscriptionsReady and Meteor.default_connection._subscriptions, but neither is reactive.

Comment: How are you subscribing to the collection? Where exactly?

Comment: Mostly through template-level subscriptions, in a lot of templates

Comment: why are you need reactive var? there is already built-in reactive helper to help you figure out when subscriptions are ready. `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}`and if you need to check all subscriptions do this on top of the template for example on the "layout" template that holds everything.

Comment: So, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

A very dirty solution, take it as a workaround if nothing else is posted:

```
reactiveAllSubscriptionsReady = new ReactiveVar(false);

Meteor.setInterval(function() {
  reactiveAllSubscriptionsReady.set(DDP._allSubscriptionsReady());
}, 50);
```

Basically poll the non-reactive variable until it changes. Does only work with simple values (integers, booleans, `null` and such.)
Do not use with arrays, objects, or functions.
Do not use in large scale applications.
Do not use at all such strategy is possible. It's a memory leak waiting to occur.

However, if you really need this functionality and don't really care, there you go.

Comment: This is actually a good answer, but I'm looking for something 'less dirty'. Maybe that's the only way though